# Cannot resolve method getApplication()

Tags: android

I created an Android global variable in my App and when I try to access it in my activitys with getApplication I get the Error:

> Cannot resolve method getApplication()

My code in the class that extends Application:

```
    package com.example.user.app;

    import android.app.Application;


    public class answer extends Application {

           private String answer1;

            public String getSomeVariable() {
                 return answer1;
              }

            public void setanswer1(String one) {
                this.answer1 = one;
                }
        }
```

My code in the activity:

```
       package com.example.user.pilz_app;

       import android.content.Intent;
       import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
       import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
       import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
       import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
       import android.view.View;
       import android.widget.ImageButton;

       public class QuestionOne extends AppCompatActivity {

             @Override
                  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                  setContentView(R.layout.activity_question_one);

            ImageButton half = findViewById(R.id.half);
            half.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionOne.this, QuestionTwo.class);
            startActivity(intent);
           ((answer) this.getApplication()).setanswer1("half");
           }

       });
```

Comment: Have you register `answer` class in Manifest?

Comment: Try `QuestionOne.this.getApplication()`

Comment: I have tested your code it's also working fine..if you already added `answer ` class in your manifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using anonymous class reference as **this**

```
   half.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionOne.this, QuestionTwo.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                ((answer) this.getApplication()).setanswer1("half");
            }
```

See `this` at this point pointing to  OnClickListener reference not your Activity's. So what you can do is to use a fully qualified reference as below.

```
QuestionOne.this.getApplication().setanswer1("half");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your android manifest you must declare the class implementing android.app.Application (add the android:name=".answer" attribute to the existing application tag):

```
    <application 
       android:name=".answer" 
       android:icon="@drawable/youricon" 
       android:label="@string/app_name">
```

but, why not using a singleton class for storing global variables ? using Application can lead to problems -> http://www.developerphil.com/dont-store-data-in-the-application-object/

Answer (score 0):

When you use `this` inside a `View.OnClickListener` it points to that `View` where `getApplication()` method cannot be resolved since it belongs to android `Activity`. 
So you should replace `((answer) this.getApplication()).setanswer1("half")`
to either

```
((answer) getApplication()).setanswer1("half") //since you were using getApplication() in Activity it is not necessary to specify 'this' keyword here
```

or

```
((answer) QuestionOne.this.getApplication()).setanswer1("half")
```